# Windows file sharing on Layer 2 Switch

Tags: networking, network-shares

If I have a few windows computers, all on a Layer 2 switch, am I able to access the public folders of them from each other or would I need a layer 3 switch/router?

Comment: No you don't need anything special. But why even ask instead of trying?

Comment: @DanielB He probably hasn't bought the devices yet, best not to waste money and be sure if its not a topic your familiar with.

Comment: All of my network equipment is connected to routers and my shares work.  I am doing a second isolated setup and wanted to know if I need to spend money on a PoE layer 2 or 3 switch as the cost is very different but did not want to harm my current setup.  I know it would also be possible to combine a Layer 3 switch and a Layer 2 PoE switch.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a layer 2 and layer 3 switch is routing.

A layer 2 switch can only tell who a computer is by a mac address, it keeps the table of mac addresses, and sends packets to the correct destination.

A layer 3 device (You can get layer 3 switches) can go beyond that, and looks at the IP address. It can then decide where the packet needs to go based on the IP address (To the gateway, a VLAN etc.)

For your purpose, a layer 1 hub would suffice, but I would recommend a switch! The computers only need to be able to talk to each other, which anything from a hub upwards can deal with.

Assuming you are on a windows workgroup, all you need to do is set up share permissions and connect via hostname/Ip address.